# OpenID connect with Microsoft Conditional Access

Tags: android, single-sign-on, openid-connect, azure-ad-msal

I have a mobile app and a web service which uses OpenID connect to interact with various identity providers from my backend.
When using SSO, the mobile app uses a web view to display the webpage such as login.microsoftonline.com to the user and then redirect back to my app. Standard OAuth/OIDC flows.
I'm not using any IdP specific libraries from my mobile app since I want to handle all of that in my backend and have my mobile app agnostic of which IdP is being used - that is one of the purposes of OIDC, after all.

Now it turns out I need to support [Microsoft Conditional Access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-conditional-access-dev-guide) to only allow compliant devices to sign in to the Microsoft SSO webpage shown embedded in my mobile app.
Can this be handled without polluting my mobile app with Microsoft specific libraries such as MSAL? If the conditional access policy requires Edge to be used, and e.g. device management through InTune - is it enough to launch Edge instead of a standard WebView/Custom tab on Android/iOS and use normal redirect flows?

Or is Microsoft killing OIDC with their proprietary extensions, making it impossible to create agnostic client software?